# pipe out the contents directed to /dev/hpib

Tags: unix, pipe, gpib

I have a hpib device connected to my system under /dev/hpib.

1. Is it possible to redirect the GPIB commands which are sent to this device?
2. Are there any methods where I can sniff out what low level GPIB commands and response that are passed to the device /dev/hpib and recevied from the device?

Thanks in advance.
lakshmesha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello :) i don't have any hpux box right now or any hpib device but i found this:
http://www.aps.anl.gov/asd/people/mrk/epics/modules/bus/gpib/gpibCoreOsi/R1-0alpha1/gpib.html

check here, if you can build this suite it has a

```
drvGpibLogData(int onOff,int link,int addr)
onOff - (0,1) means turn logging (off,on)
link - link
addr - gpib addr. Addresses>=100 signifies extended addrsssing. 
For example 901 means  primary address 9, secondary address 1.
```

worst case you could strip the ioctls off that code :)

DsP